# Basic validation in alert boxes Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, alert

I know it is better to use form validations, but if i have an alert box in javascript and I want only a number to be entered, i put in this code and it errors out..I basically want to alleviate against alpha (upper and lower), nothing, and all special characters, i only want one number...

what do i need to add to this...

```
function getCustomerNumber() {
    var customerNumber = parseInt(prompt("Please add your number: "));
       if(customerNumber == '' || customer != null || customerNumber == [^a-zA-Z\\,\\.\\;]) {
          return prompt('Please enter your number in the numerical format #');
         } else {
    return customerNumber;
     }
    }
```

cheers!

Comment: `var customerNumber = prompt("Please add your number: ");` only after you got the input try to parse it via regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
function getCustomerNumber() {    
    var customerNumber = prompt("Please add your number: ");
    var num = parseInt(customerNumber);
    if((!num && num!==0) || !/^[^a-zA-Z\\,\\.\\;]*$/.test(customerNumber)) {
      return prompt('Please enter your number in the numerical format #');
    } else {
      return num;
    }       
}
```

but to be honnest I would do a little bit change to yours orginal idea, like this:

```
function getCustomerNumber(askMessage) {    
    var customerNumber = prompt(askMessage || "Please add your number: ");
    var num = parseInt(customerNumber);
    if((!num && num!==0) || !/^[^a-zA-Z\\,\\.\\;]*$/.test(customerNumber)) {
      return getCustomerNumber('Please enter your number in the numerical format #');
    } else {
      return num;
    }       
}
```

I know that its recursive now but hey, how many times someone can type that number.